# How to load toml file in python

Tags: python, toml

How to load toml file into a python file
that my code

python file:

```
import toml 


toml.get("first").name
```

toml file :

```
[first]
    name = "Mark Wasfy"
    age = 22
[second]
    name = "john micheal"
    age = 25
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it can be used without open as a file

```
import toml


data = toml.load("./config.toml")

print(data["first"]["name"])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import toml

with open("file.toml", "r") as f:
    data = toml.load(f)

print(data["first"]["name"])
```